# Is there a way to find out if a line of code is being executed within a "try" in Python?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Environment: Python 2.6.5, Eclipse Standard/SDK (version Kepler SR2) with Pydev

> Is there a way to find out if a line of code is being executed within
>   a "try" in Python?

The code I'm working on sometimes has try blocks that call methods, and there is a case where I need a conditional depending on if the script will be exiting with an exception vs. when the script will continue.

I need to accomplish this without setting a flag before every try statement, but if there's a way to globally override every try statement to set a flag at when it is in a try-statement and clear the flag when it is out of the try-statement that would work.

Since I am working with a huge code base, it would be too big of an effort to set a flag before starting each try block.

I have tried comparing the variables in debug mode in a try and not in a try, and I didn't notice anything I could key off of.

Example:

```
def raise_exception():
    # need way to find out if executing within a 'try' and set the boolean in_try
    # Todo: define 'in_try' here
    if in_try == True:
       raise Exception('Continuing script')
    else:
       raise Exception('Exiting script')

def hello():
    print 'hello'
    try:
        self.raise_exception()
    except:
        pass

def goodbye():
   print 'goodbye'
   self.raise_exception()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why don't you simply set `in_try` to `True` when you begin the try block and set it to `False` outside of the block?

Comment: If there is a way to do this, you probably shouldn't be using it :) - The behavior of a block shouldn't depend on this sort of thing

Comment: Your edit doesn't clear up what you are trying to do. What is the purpose of this check? Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses.  I added to the description that this is a huge code base I am working with an more complex than my example.  Try blocks are being created in many different files and methods and many times not.  In one of the methods that raises an exception, I need to know if the script will exit or not before the exception is raised.

Comment: Andy, if it's possible to globally override try-statements to set a flag when starting each try block and unset it at the end of each try block that would work.  The purpose of the check is since when a script continues it prints out the exception, but when the script ends it adds html formatting to display the exception in an html file.  And I don't want the html tags to be printed if the method was called inside a try block.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse you can run it in the debugger and set a breakpoint.

Comment: I already tried that as it says in my description.  I think i found the solution though.  The method is not actually calling Exception but instead it is raising a defined exception.  I just need to modify that defined exception.  I haven't fully tested it yet but I think that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you want to change a function's behaviour based on whether you are calling said function from a `try` block or not. Why not simply define your functions as

```
def my_func(param0, param1, called_from_try_block=False):
    pass
```

Then can call your function like so:

```
my_func(4, 2)
try:
    my_func(4, 2, True)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: The function is called hundreds of times.  Is there a way to globally override all try-statements to set a flag and clear the flag when exiting each try-statement?

Comment: No there isn't a way to do this. Even if there was a hack, it would just adds complexity and makes the code much less readable.

Comment: I would find which case is more common - is the function more often in a try block, or is it not? Then take the most common case, and make that keyword argument the default - then you will only need to change a few of the function calls (see my example)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a variable for that just

```
try:
    # need way to find out if executing within a 'try' and set the boolean in_try
    # Todo: define 'in_try' here
    print 'try is being executed'
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you set a variable called `in_try` to `False` at the top of your program, and at the beginning of the `try`, you set `in_try` to `True` as such:

```
in_try = False

if in_try == True:
    print 'In try-except!'
else:
    print 'Not in try-except!'

try:
    in_try = True
    if in_try == True:
        print 'In try-except!'
    else:
        print 'Not in try-except!'
    in_try = False
except:
    pass

if in_try == True:
    print 'In try-except!'
else:
    print 'Not in try-except!'
```

When this is run:

```
bash-3.2$ python tryexcept.py
Not in try-except!
In try-except!
Not in try-except!
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Is it possible to globally override all try statements to set the flag?